# CORS Error with Socket.io and NGROK, why does it happen and how to resolve it?

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io, ngrok

I'm implementing Socket.io and encountering a CORS error with NGROK regardless of the configuration I try.

This is my Socket.io server code:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

import { createServer } from 'http';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

const httpServer = createServer();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
  path: "/correction-socket"
});

function disconnectAllRooms(socket) {
  socket.rooms.forEach(room => {
    if (room !== socket.id) {
      socket.leave(room);
    }
  })
}

function isRoomAlreadyOccupied(payload) {
  const rooms = [];
  io.sockets.sockets.forEach((socket) => {
    socket.rooms.forEach(room => rooms.push(room))
  });
  return rooms.some(room => room === payload);
}

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('joinRoom', (room) => {
    disconnectAllRooms(socket);
    const currentRoomAlreadyOccupied = isRoomAlreadyOccupied(room);

    if (!currentRoomAlreadyOccupied) {
      socket.join(room);
      socket.emit('roomAccessed', true);
    } else {
      socket.emit('roomAccessed', false);
    }
  });

  socket.on('leftRoom', (room) => {
    io.emit('releasedRoom', room);
  });

  socket.on('disconnecting', () => {
    socket.rooms.forEach(room => {
      if (room !== socket.id) {
        io.emit('releasedRoom', room);
      }
    });
  });
});

httpServer.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on PORT ${PORT}`))
```

And this is my client connection code:

```
this.socket = io(process.env.SOCKET_CORRECTION_URL, {
        path: '/correction-socket'
      });
```

I believe the issue might not be with NGROK, given that I'm facing the same problem in a development environment.

I hope to find the solution to this CORS issue.

Answer (score 1):

ngrok uses a "stub" when accessing your site. When you connect a socket, you connect specifically to this "stub", and there naturally there is no information about cors.

You need to add an extra `ngrok-skip-browser-warning` header on the client when connecting to the socket, then the connection will go directly to the server with the socket.

Add header to connection: https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-initialization/#extraheaders

Disabling the stub: https://ngrok.com/abuse